# 2004 suzuki sv650s fuel pump does not prime or start

Tags: motorcycle, wiring, suzuki, sv650

I've just purchased this bike as a non runner due to the alarm ( datatool system 3)  I bypassed the alarm and it run like a dream.  I then proceeded to remove the ararm by following all the wires and removing the alarm, re soldering the original wires and heat sealing them.

However I'm left with 4 Black wires with green bands spare, one in a small block with some other wires no live feed.
Another from the fuse box again no live feed, 
One spliced into an orange cable with white stripe No Live feed
And the other spliced into 3 red cables with white strip and grey bands This is 12V live.

Everything lights up as it should on the dash but the fuel pump doesn't prime or start.

any suggestions would be greatly welcomed. 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: So I've now established some of the wires, one is the indicators to orange & white. one is also indicator and the other to the reds is fuel line.  Still have no fuel pump though.

Comment: Can you energize the pump manually?

Comment: Yeah I went direct to see if the pump was OK and it is.  Seems as though I have power to the pump its just not engaging.  Like the kill switch is on.  The orange with white strip wire that i've got with a spliced in is the kill switch cable but I don't know why its there.  I've also got the cable that comes from the fuze box which is also connected to the ignition feed ??? confused .com